# Publish nodes with drush?

Tags: 7, drush

I'm faced with the situation of needing to be able to publish content with Drush.  Is there a way to use Drush to publish nodes?  If there is, how can it be done?

Comment: Why do you need to publish with drush?
How exactly do you want to input nodes through drush?
And what kind of nodes are you expecting to generate? I mean, do you want to specify the title? The body? Empty nodes? Are you sure you need Drush?
Maybe the Drupal API is enough - in this case see: https://drupal.org/node/889058

Comment: I don't need to generate content.  Ideally in my scenario I'd like to be able to either target all nodes or a specific set of nodes by listing node ids.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if that is available by default (found no result on searching), but one thing that you can do is declaring your own Drush command in 3 easy steps:

1. Creating the Command File:

   > ( Give the right name to the command file and place it into a folder that Drush will look, That name must end with .drush.inc (in our case it will be publish.drush.inc) and must be placed either in the folder of a custom module on your site (will work for that site if the module is enabled) or in the .drush folder in your server’s root directory).
2. Declaring the Command Function: To declare a new Drush command you have to invoke hook_drush_command() in the file you created above and below the php opening tag. Example as below:

> function publish_drush_command() {
>     $items = array();
>     $items['publish-content'] = array(
>       'description' => 'Publish content',
>       'aliases' => array('pc'),
>       'arguments' => array(
>         'type' => 'Nodes of this type will be published',
>       ),
>     );
>     return $items;
>   }

Note: This command is declared in a file that has been placed in the .drush folder that resides in the VPS’s root folder.

Here we have declared a new command called publish-content (a new key in the $items array). The description and what’s included in the arguments key is what you will see when you run the drush help publish-content command. What’s actually helpful here is that you can also specify an alias (or shortcut) that can be run instead of the longer publish-content version. In this case, `drush publish-content` will equal `drush pc`.
3. Declare the Command Callback Function: Now you need to write the code that you want Drupal to perform when you run the custom command. The name of the function needs to be in the format: drush_command_name. (Note: dash in the command name becomes an underscore in the function name).

```
function drush_publish_content($type) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if($node->status == 0) {
      $count++;
      $node->status = 1;
      node_save($node);
    }  
  }
  if($count > 0) {
    drush_print($count . " nodes of the " . $type . " content type have been successfully published.");
  }

  else {
    drush_print("No nodes of the " . $type . " content type were published.");
  }
}
```

This callback function takes as argument the machine name of the content type of all the nodes we want published. This gets passed as a command argument like so (Example: pulish the contents of blog content-type):

> drush publish-content blogs

Drush will then print out how many nodes have been published (displaying only the number of nodes that have been in fact affected by the command).

References:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-declare-your-own-drush-commands-with-your-vps
https://github.com/edvillan15/node-tools/blob/master/node_tools.drush.inc

Comment: That looks pretty good. To create Drush commands really quickly, see https://drupal.org/project/drushify

Comment: @greg_1_anderson Seems good, Thanks for sharing this!!

Answer (score 3):

Publish a node in Drupal 8

```
drush php-eval '$node = node_load(123); $node->setPublished(true); $node->save();'
```

Publish a node node in Drupal 7

```
drush php-eval '$node = node_load(123); $node->status = 1; node_save($node);’
```

Publish all the nodes of a specific content type in Drupal 8

```
drush php-eval '$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array("type" => "here_the_type_name"));foreach($nodes as $node){ $node->setPublished(true); $node->save();}'
```

Publish all the nodes of a specific type in Drupal 7

```
drush php-eval '$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array("type" => "here_the_type_name")); foreach($nodes as $node){  $node->status = 1; node_save($node);}'
```

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 8, this worked (via Dave Burns),

```
drush php-eval '$node = node_load(2); $node->setPublished(true); $node->save();'
```

Answer (score 1):

In drupal 8 this can also be done via node name if the node id is unknown for some reason:

```
drush php-eval '$node=reset(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("node")->loadByProperties(["title"=>"Test Page"]));$node->setPublished(true);$node->save();'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in drupal 8, if you are using the core Content Moderation Module, replace:

```
$node->setPublished(true);
```

with

```
$node->set("moderation_state","published");
```